# XmlDocument c# load decode character special

Tags: c#, xmldocument

hi i have problem with xmlDocument in c#.
I have an XML string with encoded characters `&amp; and &apos;`

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.PreserveWhitespace = true;
doc.LoadXml ("<item> hello &amp; pepe and maria&apos;s </item>");
```

```
Console.WriteLine (doc.InnerText); // "<item> hello & pepe y maria's </item>"
Console.WriteLine (doc.InnerXml); // "<item> hello & pepe y maria's </item>"
```

But InnerText and InnerXML remove the coding.
I need them to keep the encoding and both InnerText or InnerXml show `<item> hello & amp; pepe and maria & apos; s </item>`

What is the right way ?

Comment: Why do you need to do this? `&amp;` is how you represent `&` in XML. I mean, you could just do a text replace yourself after parsing to re-insert the XML encoded value.

Comment: What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: Thanks, it is to sign an XML.
That XML is encoded, & i & amp ;, but xmldocument decodes it leaving the signature invalid.


XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.PreserveWhitespace = true;
doc.LoadXml ("<item> hello &amp; pepe and maria&apos;s </item>");

SignedXml signedXml = new SignedXml(doc);